# Rendering HTML from local file using webview_flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mapbox, flutter-layout, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to load an HTML code using [webview_flutter plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter)

Here is the code of my `test.html` file located on assets folder:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Add an image</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.0.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.0.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='map'></div>
<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoid2F3YW5vcG91bG9zIiwiYSI6ImNqdGc3aTh4NTBpZzYzeXA2bG44NzAzYXcifQ.ltDQ5A9BesT6oRZmUauOEQ';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    maxZoom: 22,
    zoom: 18,
    center: [-9.412696, 48.441571],
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9'
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code of my flutter page:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class SignInPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  SignInPageState createState() {
    return SignInPageState();
  }
}

class SignInPageState extends State<SignInPage> {
  WebViewController _controller;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Help')),
      body: WebView(
        initialUrl: '',
        onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
          _controller = webViewController;
          _loadHtmlFromAssets();
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  _loadHtmlFromAssets() async {
    String fileText = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/test.html');
    _controller.loadUrl( Uri.dataFromString(
        fileText,
        mimeType: 'text/html',
        encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8')
    ).toString());
  }
}
```

I always get a white page where nothing is loaded. When I replace my `test.html` file by a single line like (`<h1>HELLO</h1>`), the html is well displayed.

Comment: Is it the <script/> it's not accepting?

Comment: @David Brossard I don't know, there is no stacktrace

Comment: you could try to remove the JavaScript and see whether that has an impact. You could also just keep the part of the body and not anything else.

Comment: @wawanopoulos : Did you resolved this issue ? I am facing same issue.